# Singleton BackgroundService not started by Autofac

Tags: autofac, autofac-configuration

I am running Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 7.1.0 in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 REST API.

I have a `BackgroundService` class and configured to run as a `SingleInstance`.

My problem is that the `StartAsync` is never called. But configured *without* the `SingleInstance` statement, `StartAsync` is called.

Is this a bug, not configured correctly or maybe a misunderstanding?

Registration:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
             .AsImplementedInterfaces()
             .Except<BackgroundSendMailService>(ct => ct.As<IBackgroundSendMailService>()
                .SingleInstance())
             .PublicOnly();
```

BackgroundService:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TheNameSpace
{
    public interface IBackgroundSendMailService : IHostedService
    {
        Task SendMail(List<EmailModel> emails);
    }

    public class BackgroundSendMailService : BackgroundService, IBackgroundSendMailService
    {
        public BackgroundSendMailService()
        {

        }

        public Task SendMail(List<EmailModel> emails)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not exposed to the DI container as an `IHostedService`, so it cannot be found when looking up all those services at startup. The DI container can only resolve it when looking specifically for an `IBackgroundSendMailService`.

Change this part

```
.Except<BackgroundSendMailService>(ct => ct.As<IBackgroundSendMailService>()
                                           .SingleInstance())
```

to either this

```
.Except<BackgroundSendMailService>(ct => ct.As<IBackgroundSendMailService>()
                                           .As<IHostedService>()
                                           .SingleInstance())
```

or something like this:

```
.Except<BackgroundSendMailService>(ct => ct.AsImplementedInterfaces()
                                           .SingleInstance())
```

**Edit:** I just noticed you used the `AsImplementedInterfaces()` on the assembly registration, but I guess the `Except` won't take this into account and just use your manual registration.